# Where should I init my data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, init

I am parsing a CSV file when my iphone app loads.  This takes a few seconds I would like to throw up a splash screen while this is happening however because I am loading this data from wakeFromNib the splash screen is coming up after I am done.

So where should I do this work?

Answer (score 2):

What about loading the CSV in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` on `UIApplicationDelegate`?

Answer (score 0):

As with most tasks that block the UI, run it in a background thread and inform the main thread (to hide the splash screen) when it is done.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) for this kind of tasks. Google for [some tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?hl=&q=nsoperation+tutorial&).

**applicationDidFinishLaunching** (app-wise) or **viewDidLoad** (ViewController-wise) is good place to place the code.